# Polymorphic chaining function for Persistent models

Tags: haskell, persistent

Consider the following code:

```
import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.TH
import Database.Persist.Sqlite

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Model1
  fieldA Int
  fieldB String

Model2
  fieldC String
  fieldD Double Maybe
|]

(>->) :: Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
(>->) (Just x) _ = Just x
(>->) _ b        = b

heavyComputation1 :: [String] -> Maybe Model1
heavyComputation1 input = undefined

heavyComputation2 :: [String] -> Maybe Model1
heavyComputation2 input = undefined

heavyComputation3 :: [String] -> Maybe Model2
heavyComputation3 input = undefined

heavyComputation4 :: [String] -> Maybe Model2
heavyComputation4 input = undefined

doTheWork :: [String] -> IO ()
doTheWork input = do
  let result = (heavyComputation1 input)
               >-> (heavyComputation2 input)
               >-> (heavyComputation3 input)
               >-> (heavyComputation4 input)
  case result of
    Just x  -> runSqlite "base.db" $ do insert x; return ()
    Nothing -> return ()
```

It does not compile (of course). Only one of the `heavyComputation`s will produce value for a given input. `(>->)` is supposed to stop CPU-heavy computation when the first value is produced.

Questions:

1. Is there anything like my `(>->)` already defined?
2. What type should the `(>->)` have? I was trying to do something like `(>->) :: forall a. PersistEntity a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a` but I clearly do not understand `forall` as it doesn't seem to help.

Maybe all my design is wrong. The idea is to get one of the `Model`s constructed from the input and skip unnecessary computation without such monstrosity:

```
doTheWorkUgly :: [String] -> IO ()
doTheWorkUgly input = do
  case heavyComputation1 input of
    Just x -> runSqlite "abc.db" $ do insert x; return ()
    Nothing -> case heavyComputation2 input of
                 Just x -> runSqlite "abc.db" $ do insert x; return ()
                 Nothing -> case heavyComputation3 input of
                              Just x -> runSqlite "abc.db" $ do insert x; return ()
                              Nothing -> case heavyComputation4 input of
                                           Just x -> runSqlite "abc.db" $ do insert x; return ()
                                           Nothing -> return ()
```

My idea is to have `result` be any of the models. `insert` can polymorphically write the to the DB. I would like to have my short-circuiting "chain" operator be polymorphic as well. Help!

Comment: As for type, the type you have above is fine. Why restrict it to `PersistEntity`? But, as for your first question: it already exists! It's called `(<|>)` in the module `Control.Applicative`.

Comment: `Alternative`! That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my comment, I hadn't quite seen that your problem was that you were trying to combine two different types, `Maybe Model1` and `Maybe Model2`.

That won't work - you can't find a function to combine them nicely. (You can combine them with a nasty branching `Either` mess, but I assume you don't want that)

However, because these two models share the same `PersistentEntityBackend`, these expressions all have the same type:

```
fmap insert_ (heavyComputation1 input)
fmap insert_ (heavyComputation2 input)
fmap insert_ (heavyComputation3 input)
fmap insert_ (heavyComputation4 input)
```

That type is `(MonadIO m) => Maybe (ReaderT SqlBackend m ())`, but the important part is that the type is `Maybe a` for some `a`, and also that they don't represent having actually done any SQL persistence yet, but just represent the action to do some SQL persistence. Now that they're the same type, we can tie them together with `<|>` as:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}

import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.TH
import Database.Persist.Sqlite
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Foldable (mapM_)
import Prelude hiding (mapM_)

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Model1
  fieldA Int
  fieldB String

Model2
  fieldC String
  fieldD Double Maybe
|]

heavyComputation1 :: [String] -> Maybe Model1
heavyComputation1 input = undefined

heavyComputation2 :: [String] -> Maybe Model1
heavyComputation2 input = undefined

heavyComputation3 :: [String] -> Maybe Model2
heavyComputation3 input = undefined

heavyComputation4 :: [String] -> Maybe Model2
heavyComputation4 input = undefined

doTheWork :: [String] -> IO ()
doTheWork input =
  mapM_ (runSqlite "base.db") $
    (insert_ <$> heavyComputation1 input)
    <|> (insert_ <$> heavyComputation2 input)
    <|> (insert_ <$> heavyComputation3 input)
    <|> (insert_ <$> heavyComputation4 input)

main :: IO ()
main = doTheWork ["hi"]
```

Here I used the alias for fmap (`<$>`) that `Control.Applicative` provides.

Comment: Oh, so in this case `fmap` transforms "Maybe value" into "Maybe an IO action on the value", chain of  `<|>`'s returns first non-Nothing action and then `runSqlite` actually performs it. Do I get it right?

Comment: Yep. Except that specifically `fmap insert_` transforms "Maybe value" to "May an IO action using value that returns `()`", which was necessary to get the same type whether the heavy computation was returning a Model1 or a Model2